# Selenium random timeout exceptions without any message

Tags: python, selenium, timeout

**Here is what I'm trying to do** and most of the time I succeed:
Basically I'm signing in on a website and then wait for a class to be in the source, then process the source code.

**The exception I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "foo.py", line 495, in <module>
report(login, password)
File "foo.py", line 430, in report
data = bar(login, password)
File "foo.py", line 113, in 
ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda browser: browser.find_elements_by_class_name("the-class-i-want"))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
raise TimeoutException(message)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ''
```

**Here is the code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import contextlib
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')) as browser:
    browser.get('mywebsite')
    login_form = browser.find_element_by_id('login-form')
    email = browser.find_element_by_name('login')
    password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    email.send_keys(login)
    password.send_keys(password)
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda browser: browser.find_elements_by_class_name("the-class-i-want"))
```

I tried this too:

```
wait_count = 0
    while wait_count < 6:
        print wait_count
        ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda browser: browser.find_elements_by_class_name("the-class-i-want"))
        if browser.find_elements_by_class_name("the-class-i-want"):
            break
        wait_count += 1
```

I get the same exception.

I am currently trying this :

```
wait_count = 0
while wait_count < 6:
    try:
        ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda browser: browser.find_elements_by_class_name("the-class-i-want"))
        if browser.find_elements_by_class_name("the-class-i-want"):
            break
    except:
        wait_count += 1
        continue
```

I haven't got to the point where it fails, I'm still testing it.

Sorry this is very long. But I'd like to find a pythonic and clean solution to those random timeouts.

Another info that could help too: the signing in process is sometimes very long, but even with a several minutes wait, it throws the exception.

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback of the exception? Also, are you sure the condition you specify is satisfied? (otherwise, it will timeout after `10` seconds)

Comment: Can you try to use another WebDriver where you can actually see what is happening on the page? Maybe it's just that the condition you are waiting for is not being met.

Comment: From a testing point of view, do you really want to Assert login success by the presence of a class? Have you considered validating text or a visible element?

Comment: @amey what do you mean by validating text/visible element?

Comment: @jadkik94 that would mean that the signing in action didn't work? Will try with a firefox webdriver and let you know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer I got after contacting Adam Goucher:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import contextlib
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def waiter(browser):
    elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('the-class-i-want')
    if len(elements) != 0:
        return elements
    return False

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')) as browser:
    browser.get('mywebsite')
    login_form = browser.find_element_by_id('login-form')
    email = browser.find_element_by_name('login')
    password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    email.send_keys(login)
    password.send_keys(password)
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(waiter)
```

And this works perfectly fine!