# Selenium getting all of the attributes python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get all of the elements on a page, but it has unlimited scrolling.  I try to scroll down the page and then get the attributes but it is not picking them all up?  For some reason I only get about half of them?

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A2A46BUQRGSAB0/ref=cm_cr_dp_pdp")
 lastHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
 while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    print newHeight, lastHeight
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
       break
   lastHeight = newHeight
tree = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
product = tree.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-base product-title pr-multiline-ellipses-container"]//text()')[::3]
print len(product)
```

Comment: I want to see if a person reviewed a specific product in my list.  So I am just trying to get the product names on there profile.  @birthofearth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to wait the scrolling take effect. Otherwise, you will get the source code before the update done.

Simple, but not perfect workaround is to use `time.sleep` with enough time:

```
import time

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(1)  # <---
newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

Comment: I still do not get >25 reviews when this profile does have it even when I am sleeping the script for 5 seconds.

Comment: @bentest, Even if I do it manually with  the browser, 75 (25 * 3) is the maximum I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Selenium Python bindings doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html), you could try to use a wait, either implicit or explicit.
This answer from SO [Selenium random timeout exceptions without any message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820526/1902874) might be helpful to implement explicit wait implementation.

For implicit wait you might try something like that (not tested):

```
def reached_bottom(driver):
    try:
        return driver.find_element_by_class_name("no-more")        
    except:
        return False    

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)    
driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A2A46BUQRGSAB0/ref=cm_cr_dp_pdp")

while not reached_bottom(driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

product = ...
```

I used the `no-more` class that shows up at the end as stop condition, assuming it's added to the DOM when end is reached. but again, didn't test it.