# python selenium login session error: TimeoutException: Message:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I was trying to login with python-selenium and here are my codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait #as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(“ — incognito”)
decanter = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, chrome_options=option)
BASE_URL = 'www.decanter.com/wine-reviews/search#order[updated_at]=desc&page={0}'
decanter.get("http://"+BASE_URL.format(1))
delay_sec = 1
decanter.find_element_by_css_selector("button.secondary").click()
```

Everything worked until here, where the last line of code above opened up the popup login window, as shown in the screenshot here:
[image]

The following codes with which I was trying to log in met with the "TimeoutException: Message:" error.

```
USER = "userid"
PASSWORD = "passwd"
WebDriverWait(decanter, delay_sec).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-widget/screen-layout/main/current-screen/screen-login//p[1]/input'))).send_keys(USER)
decanter.find_element_by_css_selector('/html/body/app-widget/screen-layout/main/current-screen/screen-login/p[2]/input').send_keys(PASSWORD)
decanter.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()
```

I have tried [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432412/selenium-random-timeout-exceptions-without-any-message) which threw out the same error. Nor is the amount of wait time or the path is the issue here I'm positive.

Further attempts and error messages are:

```
>>> WebDriverWait(decanter, delay_sec).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='inputlabel' and contains(.,'E-mail')]//following::p[1]/input[@type='text']"))).send_keys(USER)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sheng/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locators were a little off. The code below should work.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(decanter, delay_sec)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='piano-id-']"))
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[fieldloginemail]'))).send_keys(USER)
decanter.find_element_by_css_selector('input[fieldloginpassword]').send_keys(PASSWORD)
decanter.find_element_by_css_selector('button[actionlogin]').click()
# once you are done with the content inside the iframe, switch context back to default
decanter.switch_to.default_content()
```

NOTE: It's not a good idea to use XPaths with more than just a few levels, especially those that start with the HTML tag. They are very likely to break with even small changes to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks JeffC for your prompt comment!! I'm sure positive your code makes sense... but it still returned the same error... What else would you think might have gone bonkers in my codes...?

Comment: I would up the delay to 5, maybe 10 seconds. Maybe the site is loading slowly.

Comment: thanks @JeffC, but I actually set it to 20 and saw the loading was complete every time

Comment: I see that the dialog is inside an `IFRAME`. Added code to take care of switching to it and back out.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to send text to the *userid* and *passwd* field so instead of *expectedconditions* clause as `visibility_of_element_located` you need to use the clause [**`element_to_be_clickable`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

```
USER = "userid"
PASSWORD = "passwd"
WebDriverWait(decanter, delay_sec).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='inputlabel' and contains(.,'E-mail')]//following::p[1]/input[@type='text']"))).send_keys(USER)
decanter.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='input-group']/input[@type='password']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
```

Note : There is no best practices whether to use CSS/XPath while traversing the DOM. CSS and XPath both have their own pros and cons.

---

### Update

As I mentioned in my comments as per your updated snapshot of the HTML the element is within an `<iframe>` tag. Hence you have to switch to the intended frame as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.ID,"piano-id-XSavU"))
USER = "userid"
PASSWORD = "passwd"
WebDriverWait(decanter, delay_sec).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//current-screen/screen-login//label[@class='inputlabel' and contains(.,'E-mail')]//following::p[1]/input[@type='text']"))).send_keys(USER)
decanter.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='input-group']/input[@type='password']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
```

Comment: Traverse up the HTML and cross-check if the `<main>` tag is within an frame then you need to switch to the intended frame first. Update the question with text based formatted HTML and error stack trace for further analysis.

Comment: I tried and it was still the same error message... could it be because the cursor had already been there at the input box when I looked at the controlled screen, in which case do I still have to switch to it?

Comment: thanks, but still the same error right after the first line of code.